# ¿Como obtener el key de un objeto solo una vez en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto

Hola desde ya gracias por sus respuestas mi problema es el siguiente, tengo este array de objetos:

```
var rowsData = [
  {"id":1,"nombre":"darinel","edad":"2"},
  {"id":2,"nombre":"yair","edad":"24"},
  {"id":3,"nombre":"Daniel","edad":"24"},
  {"id":4,"nombre":"Saul","edad":"24"}
];
```

Quiero obtener de rowsData un array de arrays de la siguiente forma:

```
[
   ["id","nombre","edad"],
   [1, "darinel", "2"],
   [2, "yair", "24"],
   [3, "Daniel", "24"],
   [4, "Saul", "24"]
]
```

Estoy intentado de la siguiente manera el problema es que me repeti las keys del objeto en cada iteración.

```js
var rowsData = [
  {"id":1,"nombre":"darinel","edad":"2"},
  {"id":2,"nombre":"yair","edad":"24"},
  {"id":3,"nombre":"Daniel","edad":"24"},
  {"id":4,"nombre":"Saul","edad":"24"}
];


var rows = [];

rowsData.map(function(row) {
     rows.push(Object.keys(row))
     rows.push(Object.values(row))
});
 
console.log(rows);
```

El problema que tengo es la repetición de mis keys.
De ante mano muchas gracias cualquier consejo o enlace a alguna doucumentación lo agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se están repitiendo porque has puesto `rows.push(Object.keys(row))` dentro de `.map()`, por lo tanto, se va a repetir por cada item en `rowsData`. Puedes ejecutar `rows.push(Object.keys(rowsData[0]))` antes de llamar a `rowsData.map()`

```js
var rowsData = [
  {"id":1,"nombre":"darinel","edad":"2"},
  {"id":2,"nombre":"yair","edad":"24"},
  {"id":3,"nombre":"Daniel","edad":"24"},
  {"id":4,"nombre":"Saul","edad":"24"}
];


var rows = [];

rows.push(Object.keys(rowsData[0]))

rowsData.map(function(row) {     
     rows.push(Object.values(row))
});
 
console.log(rows);
```